# Python Regular Expression creation

Tags: python, regex

I tried running the following code:

```
lin = ',11'
pat = ',([11|01])$'
re.search(pat, lin)
```

since pat has ',11' and lin also has ',11' I should get an object returned by re.search

But in this case, it is returning None.

Can anybody please help me out? I'm pretty confused over it.

Answer (score 5):

You are using a character class: `[...]`. These act as *sets*; any of the characters you name in them will match. Your character class will match any `1`, `|` or `0` character, the 3 unique characters you named in the class. You didn't specify a multiplier after the `[...]` character class, so it'll match just *one* character:

```
>>> re.match(',([11|01])$', ',1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106d1648>
>>> re.match(',([11|01])$', ',0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106d16c0>
>>> re.match(',([11|01])$', ',|')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106d1648>
```

Remove the class if you want to match exact characters:

```
pat = ',(11|01)$'
```

which matches either the literal characters `11` or `01`:

```
>>> re.match(',(11|01)$', ',11')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106d16c0>
>>> re.match(',(11|01)$', ',01')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106d1648>
```

or, if you still want to use a character class:

```
pat = ',([01]1)$'
```

Now the parenthesis are no longer required to group the `|` *or* operator, so you can drop those to simplify things down to:

```
pat = ',[01]1$'
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.match(',[01]1$', ',01')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106bc5e0>
>>> re.match(',[01]1$', ',11')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1106bc648>
>>> re.match(',[01]1$', ',00') is None
True
>>> re.match(',[01]1$', ',10') is None
True
>>> re.match(',[01]1$', ',|') is None
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to the `[...]` brackets, your regular expression matches one character, which may be `0`, `1`, or `|`.

I think you wanted more like `,(11|01)$`.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
re.search(r',(11|01)',lin)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[11|01]` is **not** `11 or 01`, it is actually `1 or | or 0`.

Try using this:

```
,[10]1$
```

That would be a comma, then `[1 or 0]`, then `1`, then an anchor to the end of string.

You could also just use this:

```
,((11)|(01))$
```